# HTML5 FileReader() functions not getting called

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why neither `readSuccess()` or `readFailure()` are getting called in the following:

```
function readMyFile(){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = readSuccess;
    reader.onerror = readFailure;
    reader.readAsText("test.txt");

    function readSuccess(evt){
      alert(evt.target.result);
    }

    function readFailure(evt) {
      alert("Did not read file!");
    }
}
```

When I step though the code in the Chrome javascript debugger, it steps past the `reader.readAsText("test.text");` command, but then exits the whole function, never calling `readSuccess()` or `readFailure()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a file with a string in `reader.readAsText()`, it needs to be a reference to a `Blob`: [see the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-filereader).

You should be getting the `Blob` from a file-type input field, check out [these awesome examples](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.  What if I want to specify a text file myself (this is for an internal file that I'll be reading only once).

Comment: Grabbing a `File` from the `FileList` of an input element is currently the only way to get at local files from a browser with javascript - but thank your stars for that, prior to HTML5 there was no way at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript